# Is this equation of state original?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, equation-of-state

I created this equation of state as a personal undergraduate summer project (here is the [link](https://www.docdroid.net/ygLo4Gu/equation-of-state.pdf.html))  seven years ago:

$$\frac{PV}{nRT}-1 \propto \left(\frac{nRT}{PV}\right)^2 \left[\left(\frac{nRT}{PV}\right)^2 - 1\right]$$

I tried to show it to my professors but none of them replied to my emails. I had since forgotten about it until I recently came across it in the cloud. Here is a table comparing its theoretical predictions for the critical temperatures of various gases to the actual experimental values

[image: Predicted and experimental critical temperatures]

Comment: How do you use it in order to make predictions of $T_c$?

Comment: @user1420303 I'm guessing $$\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V}\right)_T = \left(\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial V^2}\right)_T = 0$$ although the link says $T_c = \varepsilon/(k \ln 2)$ (not sure how the derivation works)

Comment: @orthocresol Sorry, I was not able to open the link before, it took me to the table image with the SE App . I am going to read it from my PC in minutes.

Comment: @user1420303 It was broken just now, I fixed it. ;)

Comment: I think it is original, although I'm not sure about some points in the derivation.

Comment: @user1420303 Is there any hope of turning this into something publishable?

Comment: @KingChem , I hope so, but I honestly have to say that I disagree in some points of the derivation.

Comment: @user1420303 Funny that you have said that, for after hearing no reply from my professors I did submit it to this physical chemistry journal but they replied with a rejection saying that "it makes incorrect assumptions". After that I lost interest and discarded it until I rediscovered it. However  it works, therefore either the core of it is correct but it was arrived at in an incorrect way or the existing theory is incorrect. I'm not so big-headed as to believe that I've overthrown decades of chemical knowledge so it must be former. Maybe amended by a professional a journal may accept it?

Comment: I can assure that, I hope so. I read your work with enthusiasm but I do not agree with:
1) Z-1 be proportional to U(r).
2) Even accepting 1), when you assumed U(r)=0 for ideal gas law behaviour and replaced according to obtain the $NkT/(pV)$, as you imposed ideal gas behaviour that should be 1, and it is valida for every $V$. Also you assumed it in the right hand side but not in the left hand side.

Comment: Then after you solve for $V$ ( I don't know how did you do that), you relate the roots to different energy levels, but you first fixed the energy to only one value.
I would don't know how to transform it in something that looks consistent to me. But the way, the results are amazing to me.
I am sorry but I preferred to be sincere.

Comment: @user1420303 Thanks for your support. I haven't done chemistry for years so I'll look over the points you made and get back to you tomorrow (it's 1:30 am now). The site is asking me if I want to move the conversation to chat, do you want to do that?

Comment: @KingChem , there is no problem, but not today, I have a lot of commitments and don't have extra time until tomorrow

Comment: @user1420303 to your first question: U(r) is a measure of the attractive force between molecules, Z is a measure of the average distance between molecules. it follows that if U(r) is increased, Z is reduced making Z-1 increase and if U(r) is decreased, Z is increased making Z-1 decrease. Therefore Z varies in direct proportion to U(r). To your second question: I shouldn't have wrote that, PV=zNkT and that is always valid. To your third question: I'm just saying that it's a quintic so by the fundamental theorem of algebra it will always give five roots.

Comment: @user1420303 To your fourth question: I just noticed that the root with the largest value was always P/nRT.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, **this equation of state is original**. While I cannot absolutely guarantee that it has never been used or proposed before, I can say that I have not encountered it in any “classical” model — and I teach thermodynamics and statistical physics, so I have seen *many* textbooks and classical exercices :)

Extending beyond the question of originality, I read your demonstration and what bothers me to some extent is the link you establish between $Z$ (the compression factor) and $U(r)$, the intermolecular potential energy. First, let's state that linking $Z$ to $U$ is indeed a common way to derive equations of state. However, the way you are doing it is lacking a sound basis. The sentence ***“From these explanations it can be said that $Z-1=U(r)$”*** (page 1) is the problem:

1. Yes, if $U(r)>0$ then $Z>1$, and the other way around… but that does not mean that the two quantities are proportional.
2. In fact, $Z$ is a scalar (function of $P$ and $T$), while $U(r)$ is a function of distance (and not thermodynamic variables). So they cannot be linked directly.

You intuited between $Z$ and $U$, which exists, but it needs to be formalized a bit more carefully. Standard approaches to do so rely on perturbation theory or mean-field method. You can check for examples [the classical derivations of the van der Waals equation of state](http://www.nyu.edu/classes/tuckerman/stat.mech/lectures/lecture_10/node3.html) to see how this can be done. But it requires some fundamentals of statistical physics…